# Filter integer array of jsonb column in postgres using EF Core and NpgSql

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I want to filter rows based on json array of integers, for example, my table looks like this

```
| Id  | Name       | TypeJson |
| --- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1   | Name One   | [1,2]    |
| 2   | Name Two   | [2,3]    |
| 3   | Name Three | [4,7]    |
```

where Id is type of int, Name - text and TypeJson - jsonb.

I'm trying to filter the rows by following query

```
await _dbContect.Table
.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TypeJson) && 
            EF.Functions.JsonExistAny(x.TypeJson, "2")
.ToListAsync();
```

I expect to get 1 and 2 rows as a result but I'm getting unexpected error

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: function btrim(jsonb, unknown) does not exist
...
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42883
    MessageText: function btrim(jsonb, unknown) does not exist
    Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Position: 593
    File: parse_func.c
    Line: 528
    Routine: ParseFuncOrColumn
```

am I supposed to pass `"2"` in some specific format or what is the exception thrown by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted this problem on npgsql github and as expected that's a problem on my side, as the column is jsonb type string functions like `IsNullOrEmpty()` and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` can't be applied on it, moreover it's not even needed as EF json functions will filter null values as false anyways.

[Link to the issue on github](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2592)